# Beamer Table of Content is broken when using \framebreak

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, page-breaking, vspace, allowframebreaks

When using `\framebreak` in beamer TOC I get a ugly formatting in the next frame.

My TOC is too long, so I decided to split it up.
The first page renders well.  The space before the first section thats printed is missing in the second one after the break.

```
\documentclass[14pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Inhaltsverzeichnis}
  \setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]
  \tableofcontents[sections={1-4},hideallsubsections]
  \tableofcontents[sections={5-8},hideallsubsections]
\end{frame}

\section{Section 1}
\section{Section 2}
\section{Section 3}
\section{Section 4}
\section{Section 5}
\section{Section 6}
\section{Section 7}
\section{Section 8}

\end{document}
```

Produces:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described in the beamer user guide, the option `allowframebreaks` is evil -- and you don't actually need it. As you are already manually splitting the toc, you could just as well use overlays:

```
\documentclass[14pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle<1>{Inhaltsverzeichnis i}
  \frametitle<2>{Inhaltsverzeichnis ii}
  \only<1>{\tableofcontents[sections={1-4},hideallsubsections]}
  \only<2>{\tableofcontents[sections={5-8},hideallsubsections]}
\end{frame}

\section{Section 1}
\section{Section 2}
\section{Section 3}
\section{Section 4}
\section{Section 5}
\section{Section 6}
\section{Section 7}
\section{Section 8}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: how long is your talk? :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle :P

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it is for my bachelor thesis. Not even that long, just many sections :D

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Good point, I like that. But then it does not enumerate the TOC like it is with the framebreak. That’s why I didn’t want to do it that way.

Comment: @OliverHihn See my edit